# Saudi Arabia mobile and land line numbers regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to validate Saudi Arabia phone number on my bootstrap form, but I keep getting invalid error.

Here is the regex I am using presently.

```
/^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/
```

```js
function validateContact(thisObj) {
  let fieldValue = thisObj.val();
  let pattern = /^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/;
  if (pattern.test(fieldValue)) {
    $(thisObj).addClass('is-valid');
  } else {
    $(thisObj).addClass('is-invalid');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="validate()">
  <div>
    <label for="contact_no1">Contact Number</label>
    <input id="contact_no1" name="contact_no1" type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact_no1" placeholder="" value="" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please enter a valid contact number.
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have created a proper snippet. Please add relevant JS, CSS and HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also `onsubmit="validate()"` should likely be `onsubmit="return validate()"` where validate returns true for a valid number

Comment: Have a look here https://regex101.com/r/ddnSJC/1

Comment: I don't have any issue with submitting the form cos I have other fields that works well, my problem is the regex validation for the phone number. Everything works aside that.

Comment: Can you give some example phone numbers which should work?

Comment: I want something like this +966xxxxxxxxx or +966 xx xxxxxxx

Comment: @olasunkanmi Your regex does not take spaces into account. How would that format look like if the number starts with 009665 or   9665 or +9665 for example from your alternation at the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is easy to match the numbers:

```
^((?:[+?0?0?966]+)(?:\s?\d{2})(?:\s?\d{7}))$
```

Comment: @olasunkanmi That pattern can be written as `^[+?096]+\s?\d{2}\s?\d{7}$` and would also match `??????????? 000000000` due to the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I would try it out.

Comment: in case if you want to use this just use call group 1 to achieve it again that's why i made it in a group.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar The whole match is inside group 1 which is the only captured group and will match more than the phone number. https://regex101.com/r/f2cj7A/1

Comment: This doesn't work for mobile numbers without any prefex for eg.`5393*****`

Answer (score 4):

With RegExp Class would be very easy. Here a example:

```js
var regex = new RegExp(/^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
regex.test('0501234567'); // return true;
regex.test('0521234567'); // return false;
```

Comment: that is more flexible and valid

Answer (score 1):

I use the following pattern:

```
(?:\+?0*?966)?0?5[0-9]{8}
```

Given there is no spaces, it will match numbers like:

```
966512345678
+966512345678
00966512345678
512345678
0512345678
```

In case that you need to normalize the number, capture the number `512345678` using the following pattern:

```
(?:\+?0*?966)?0?(5[0-9]{8})
```

and from there you can add `0` or `966` to the captured number.